# Oracle stored procedure to return a result set

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm totally new to Oracle, and I need to write a stored procedure that will return a result set. The stored procedure will be called from SQL Server using a linked server.
I know I can use a ref cursor to return a resultset from PL/SQL server, but I've also seen stored procedures returning sort of arrays (declared as Table of Number for example) and then return this with the result.
Which is the proper way to do this?

Comment: I presume that you will be calling your procedure from Java. In that case procedure will be called directly from Oracle or through SQL Server?

Comment: The procedure will be called from SQL Server using a linked server.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation on Oracle forums and my own testings...
A Ref Cursor is the appropriate way.
The associate arrays will not work properly using the oracle oledb provider.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is you can't return a ref cursor if your query crosses a db link on your oracle server.  The two limitations together are a super painful.

Comment: Well, it will come through a linked server in SQL Server, but directly from Oracle, I tested it already and that does work.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't super clear, if you join or query accross a db link in Oracle you can't return a ref cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Oracle XE in a Docker container and using their sample database.

Here's the stored procedure that takes a parameter and returns a set of records.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE customer_orders(cust_id IN NUMBER, cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS 
BEGIN 
    OPEN cur FOR 
        SELECT * 
        FROM orders 
        WHERE customer_id = cust_id; 
end;
/
```

Here's the Perl that executes the procedure, passing the customer id as a parameter, and processing the returned results set.

```
use DBI;
use DBD::Oracle qw(:ora_types);
 
# get the database connection
$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:localhost/xepdb1", "ot", "Orcl1234") || die(DBI->errstr());

$sth = $dbh->prepare("BEGIN customer_orders(?, ?); END;");

$sth->bind_param(1, 49);

$sth->bind_param_inout(2, \$rsh, 0, {ora_type => ORA_RSET});

$sth->execute();

while ( @row = $rsh->fetchrow_array ){
    foreach ( @row ){
        print "$_\t";
    };
    print "\n";
}

$dbh->disconnect;
```

I hope this saves all who pass this way the time it took me to figure it out.

Luck.